# Update Variable Values from Data based on Symbol

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

My program has three variables that will differ depending on the Ticker Symbol I have open in my chart.

The three program variables are:

```
TopThresh
BtmThresh
HoldDays
```

I thought that I can define values for those variables per ticker such as:

```
// $DIA Values
DIA_TopThresh = 0.9
DIA_BtmThresh = -0.7
DIA_HoldDays = 3

// $QQQ Values
QQQ_TopThresh = 0.6
QQQ_BtmThresh = -0.5
QQQ_HoldDays = 4

etc...
```

I can get the ticker using: "syminfo.ticker".

But how do I update my three program variables with the value based on the ticker?

I would need to update the values to be DIA_... or QQQ_... depending on the ticker being viewed.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Just write some if conditions and check for the current tickerid.

Example:

```
if (syminfo.tickerid == "BINANCE:BTCUSDT")
    TopThresh := DIA_TopThresh
    BtmThresh := DIA_BtmThresh
    HoldDays := DIA_HoldDays
else if (syminfo.tickerid == "BINANCE:ETHUSDT")
    TopThresh := QQQ_TopThresh
    BtmThresh := QQQ_BtmThresh
    HoldDays := QQQ_HoldDays
else  // A different ticker is selected
    TopThresh := default_value
    BtmThresh := default_value
    HoldDays := default_value
```